Laravel Pest - Refresh Database for one certain test in a file
I'm using Laravel with Pest. I have a file contains three test and out of which only one test involves db operation so I want to make sure db is only refreshed for that one test. So, I don't want to use uses(RefreshDatabase::class); on the top file because I don't want to refresh db before each of the tests. So that I can save some execution time of running tests. What I did is:
//uses(RefreshDatabase::class);

it('test 1', function () {
    //no db operations here
});

it('test 2', function () {
    //no db operations here
});


it('successfully stores social connector', function () {
    $repo->storeSocialConnector(["platform"=>"wix"]); //suppose it successfully stores record in social_connectors table

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('social_connectors', [
        'platform' => 'fooBar',
    ]);

})->uses(RefreshDatabase::class);

but the above code don't refreshed the database when I run third test.
How I confirm this?
suppose I run this test two times likes
./vendor/bin/pest tests/Feature/Http/SomeTest.php --filter 'successfully stores social connector'
I got below output:
 FAILED  Tests\Feature\Http\SomeTest > it successfully stores social connector
  Failed asserting that a row in the table [social_connectors] matches the attributes {
    "platform": "fooBar"
}.

Found: [
    {
        "platform": "wix",
    },
    {
        "platform": "wix",
    }
].

See, when I run the test second time it shows me it found two records in table, however it should say me it found just one record not two.
It means when first tim test failed the record is created and that record didn't got cleared when I run the test second time. However db should be cleared after first try fail.
How to make sure db should be cleared after test executed so that when I execute test second time the data from last run don't show up?

You are going to have to to put uses(RefreshDatabase::class) at the top of the file. If that's too much of an issue maybe you can consider extracting this test to its own test file

What is the issue of having RefreshDatabase at the top? Why can't you run it?

if I use uses(RefreshDatabase::class) on top then db is going to be refreshed for each of the tests and I don't want this. Why should I refresh db for those tests that don't involve database

@apokryfos I can't make new file
actually I'm arranging files in a certain way so I'm limited to using same file

You could try running it manually e.g. run app(RefreshDatabase::class)->refreshDatabase() at the beginning of your test (though it's not a great solution, I still recommend moving this test to its own file).

@apokryfos,  I did but got error "Target [Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase] is not instantiable."

@apokryfos he can't do t hat because RefreshDatabase is a trait. Author, what you are saying makes sense, why would you run migrations on a test that does not use database at all? But, what Apokryfos is saying is also true. There is one catch (I have no idea how Pest works, I HATE it), but when you use RefreshDatabase, it migrates:fresh the database, then runs seeders if any, and finally starts a transaction. When a test finishes, the transaction is rolled back, and when the next test starts, a new transaction starts, it does not migrate:fresh the database again, so it will still be fast
